# why Rust str::parse() define generic type but not use

Tags: rust

```rust
impl str {
    ...
    #[inline]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    pub fn parse<F: FromStr>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err> {
        FromStr::from_str(self)
    }
}
```

What's the use of calling interfaces method `from_str`

Comment: This makes it possible to parse arbitrary types, including user-defined types, provided that they implement `FromStr`.

Comment: It means that `"foo".parse()` is sugar for `FromStr::from_str("foo")`, and `"foo".parse::<MyType>()` is sugar for `<MyType as FromStr>::from_str("foo")`. In the first two examples the type to convert to is determined from context, and in the second two it's given explicitly. In both cases the type to convert to must implement `FromStr`, but the point of `parse()` is that it's easier on the eyes and allows use in chained expressions.

Comment: thanks, I understand a little. Because I met example someone_function("foo".parse().unwrap() )
At first, I went to str:: parse, but I couldn't see what was returned. Later, I found that there will be some_function to implicitly call the from of the parameter::from_str, this has always puzzled me. Now it's a little clear

Comment: Yes, you observed Rust's type inference in action. In that case if `someone_function()` accepts `SomeType`, then `"foo".parse().unwrap()` will be automatically inferred to mean `"foo".parse::<SomeType>().unwrap()`.